# question from SAT

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I'm so confused about this question.

> Jesse Jackson's Rainbow PUSH _______ to encourage diverse populations to become socially and politically active, was created in 1996 by the merging of 2 groups Jackson had previously founded

We're offered 5 options to fill in the blank:

1. coalition was established
2. coalition is established
3. coalition, establishing
4. coalition, which being established
5. coalition, established

The official, correct answer is 5, but I just cannot understand why 1 is wrong?

Comment: Let's move this question to [ELL.se].

Answer (score 7):

1 is wrong because using it gives two finite predicates joined only by a comma. Bracket out the modifiers and here's what you end up with:

> Jesse Jackson's Rainbow PUSH Coalition was established <sub>for this reason</sub> , was created in 1996 <sub>in this way</sub>.

5, however, subordinates the *established* clause, so you have only one finite predicate:

> Jesse Jackson's Rainbow PUSH Coalition, established <sub>for this reason</sub> , was created in 1996 <sub>in this way</sub>.